# Autoincremet no SQLite não está funcionando no Android

Tags: android, sqlite

O autoincrement não está funcionando nas minhas tabelas no SQLite.

Tabela:

```
db.execSQL("create table usuario(_idUsuario integer primary key autoincrement, nome text not null, email text not null, senha text not null)");
```

Insert:

```
public String insertUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long resultado;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("nome", usuario.getNome());
    values.put("email", usuario.getEmail());
    values.put("senha", usuario.getSenha());

    resultado = db.insert("usuario", null, values);

    if (resultado == -1) {
        return "Usuário não foi criado!";
    } else {
        return "Usuário foi criado com sucesso";
    }
}
```

Insiro os valores através do código abaixo:

```
 usuario.setNome(cadNome);
 usuario.setEmail(cadEmail);
 usuario.setSenha(cadSenha);
 DBControle db = new DBControle(getApplicationContext());

 String a = db.insertUsuario(usuario);
```

Qualquer usuário que é criado está com o id = 0. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: pode mostrar como pega esses valores? Muito Obrigado

Comment: Anexei a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, como faz o SELECT, e traz os id = 0.

Comment: Thiago, creio que consegui obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Ok! sinta se a vontade em responder sua pergunta, assim pode ajudar outro usuário, que tiver a mesma dúvida!

Comment: Ok muito obrigado pelo conselho!

Answer (score 0):

Criar a coluna id somente como _id. Automaticamente é feito o autoincrement
Algo como:

`db.execSQL("create table usuario(_id integer primary key, nome text not null, email text not null, senha text not null)");`